# NoSuchMethodError void vs int

Tags: java

I'm going through online Java course on http://mooc.cs.helsinki.fi/ and stumbled on an error. Can't find my way around it.

```
public class NumberStatistics {

   private int count;
   private int sum;
   public NumberStatistics(){
       this.count=0;
       this.sum=0;
   }
   public void addNumber(int number){
       this.count++;
       this.sum+=number;
   }
   public int amountOfNumbers(){
       return this.count;
   }
   public int sum(){
       return this.sum;
   }
   public double average(){
       if(this.count==0||this.sum==0){
           return 0;
       }
       return (double)this.sum/this.count;
   }
}
```

And this is the main file

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        NumberStatistics stats = new NumberStatistics();

        stats.addNumber(3);
        stats.addNumber(5);
        stats.addNumber(1);
        stats.addNumber(2);
        System.out.println("Amount: " + stats.amountOfNumbers());
        System.out.println("sum: " + stats.sum());
        System.out.println("average: " + stats.average());
    }
}
```

When i try to run it, it comes with an error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:  NumberStatistics.addNumber(I)I
at Main.main(Main.java:8)
```

If I change

```
public void addNumber
```

to

```
public int addNumber
```

with return value. It goes through fine but is not accepted by their server as this method has to have specific name(void). What is the problem? I'm lost.

P.S. I've tinkered a little and it seems working now. Didn't change any code. Not sure what caused it to fail...Going to examine it. Thanks for your input.

Comment: You are not re-compiling your `Main` class. If you use an IDE or build tool it will make sure everything which needs to be compiled is recompiled.

Comment: I use NetBeans 8.2

Comment: clean your project....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just used your code in my Java SE Enviroment i got this:

Amount: 4
sum: 11
average: 2.75

Well, i didn't see any problem, but did you say that you're using a server?

this error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:  NumberStatistics.addNumber(I)I
```

at Main.main(Main.java:8)

As I know is because your class dosn't have that method, so in my humble opinion i suggest you to compile again the class using the void you want and refresh the server (restart) and you should see the change, because as i Said it worked fine in my SE enviroment